# NSDateFormatting Issue in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following piece of code,

```
NSDate *date = nil;
NSString *departureTime = @"Mon Oct 24 00:00:00 GMT 2011";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss GMT yyyy"];
date = [df dateFromString:departureTime];
[df release];

NSLog(@"Date : %@", date);
```

I am always getting nil,
 What is wrong in this code ?

Answer (score 1):

While setting the date format, the time zone format is not proper.

Change the line as follows:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd hh:mm:sss Z yyyy"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are geting nil just because of date format you have set -> "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss GMT yyyy"

If you cannot provide right format for the date it will not provide you a valid output.

For valid format parameter to get date in your format for [click Me](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)